# Expose specific parts of the Backlog and let users report bugs in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Posting this here since it got closed on stackoverflow:

We are working with Azure DevOps to organize our development process. Recently we started to additionally develop a fork of our standard product directly for a customer.

Is it possible to let them view a specific part of our backlog and let them report bugs directly to us with our on-boarding them completely into our project?

The customers project managers are non-technical users that feel kind of overwhelmed from ado. I already experimented with Boards but didn't get the result we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an similiar problem with Azure DevOps. It simply does not have an custome frontend. But many of our customers wanted to see progress on the current iteration tickets continuously and file bug tickets as well. We generated exports and sent them per mail for ages...

Unfortunatly we also could not onboard the customers to Azure Active Directory. So we could not add them to the Azure DevOps organization nor project.

After some research I found a solution which integrates with the Azure DevOps API and is super easy to use. You  can find the solution on [Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/de-de/marketplace/apps/aveyaramrsoftwaregbr1612902674653.ticket_studio?tab=Overview). You also can test the solution first month free.

Comment: That sounds very interesting - I will check that out.
Thank you!

Comment: We are testing TicketStudio since last week and it works like a charm! Thanks for the hint!